# "Internal server error" "HttpErrorResponse"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm trying to scan the table and show only few data which equals to cognitoUserName.
Basically the table contains multiple user data. I need to show data of only the logged in user.
Like user specific data.
So I have used field userName in which the email id which is unique of the user will be added into dynamodb table. And that userName is sortkey.

```js
#My handler Function
Partition Key is **certificateId** is unique.
Sort Key is userName will be same for some.

module.exports.getAllCertificate = async (event, context, cb) => {
  context.callBackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  let data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  cognitoUserName= data.email;
  try{
    var params = {
      TableName: CERTIFICATE_TABLE_NAME,
      FilterExpression: "userName = :userName",
      ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":userName": cognitoUserName
      }
  };
    const certiificates = await documentClient.scan(params).promise()
    console.log(JSON.stringify(certiificates));
    cb(null,send(200, certiificates));
  } catch(err){
   
    cb(null,send(500,err.message));
  }
};
```

```
error: {message: 'Internal server error'}
headers: HttpHeaders "Http failure response for https://duth-1.amazonaws.com/dev/certificateList: 502 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 502
statusText:"OK"
url: "https://uth-1.amazonaws.com/dev/certificateList"
```

Comment: Not your problem but I highly suggest looking into GSIs.

Comment: I haven't used GSI's

Comment: I noticed. If you did you wouldn't have to Scan and it would be faster are more efficient.